# Editing two fields at the same time

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, real-time

I want to be able to edit the title of an article which is duplicated in a field called "url" which is updated in real time when the user types in the title field...how do I go about this?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use jQuery. Have a look at the [Manual](http://www.jquery.com/).

```
$(function()
{
    $('#field1').keyPress(function()
    {
        $('#field2').val($(this).val());
    });
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Wcp3D/

```
$("document").ready(function ($) {
    $("input").bind('keyup', function() { $("lable").text($(this).val()) } );

});

<input type='text'/>
<label></label>
```

do you mean something like this?

Answer (score 1):

I don't have my environment configured here at work, but it should be something like that:

```
$("#url").change(function() {
 document.title = $(this).value();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a function to the change-event of field one, and update field two in that function:

```
$('#field1').change( function( ) {
   $('#field2').value( $(this).value( ) );
}
```